# Vbscript Class with functions to extract Excel data

Tags: excel, vbscript, hp-uft

i have a VB Script Class that has functions that extract specific excel data.
the problem is, each function has to open excel and thus choke my machine when the number of excel files opened become many.
is there a way to open excel only once, and then have my functions extract the data?

Here is my code.

```
Class TestData
    'User Name
    Function usrNm(filepath)    
        set ObjExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
        ObjExcel.workbooks.open ""&filepath& "\TestData\PosTestData.xls"    
            U_NAME = ObjExcel.sheets(1).cells(2,1)
            usrNm = U_NAME  
    End Function

    'User Password
    Function usrPwd(filepath)
        set ObjExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
        ObjExcel.workbooks.open ""&filepath& "\TestData\PosTestData.xls"        
            U_PASS = ObjExcel.sheets(1).cells(2,2)
            usrPwd = U_PASS
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

A class with just a function and no member data makes no sense. If you `.Close` the Workbook and `.Quit` Excel in `usrPwd()`, the function 'works' stand-alone/without a class.

If you insist on OOP, create/open the Excel.Application in `Class_Initialize` and `.Quit` it in `Class_Terminate`; `.Open` and `.Close` the Workbook in the method `usrPwd()`.

```
Class TestData
    Private ObjExcel

    Sub Class_Initialize
        Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    End Sub

    Sub Class_Terminate
        objExcel.Quit
    End Sub

    Function UserName(filepath)    
        ObjExcel.workbooks.open filepath & "\TestData\PosTestData.xls"    
        UserName = ObjExcel.sheets(1).cells(2,1)
    End Function

    Function UserPassword(filepath)
        ObjExcel.workbooks.open filepath & "\TestData\PosTestData.xls"        
        UserPassword = ObjExcel.sheets(1).cells(2,2)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Depending on how the workbook is used otherwise it might make sense to put opening and closing of the workbook into `Class_Initialize`/`Class_Terminate` as well.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I agree about dealing with the workbook at class level & thank you for the sample code.